# mysqldump: Got error: 1045 after a reinstall of the database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb

After a fresh install of wordpress I created a script in a FreeNAS jail to reinstalled old data by copying the files to my data directory and `iocage exec wordpress "mysql -u "root" -p"${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}" "${DATABASE_NAME}" < "/usr/local/www/wordpress/wordpress.sql""`
Everything works well until I try to do a mysqldump of the wordpress install again.  Then I get `mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect Command: /bin/sh -c mysqldump --single-transaction -h localhost -u root -p wordpress > /usr/local/www/wordpress/wordpress.sql failed!`
I removed the password from the above.

Any idea on how to fix the mysqldump error after a restore?  After a fresh install the mysqldump works.

Comment: It appears as though the user does not have either the correct password or permissions to access the database

Comment: Your correct.  It turns out the was password changes when importing the wordpress.sql. So I was trying to use the incorrect password.